# Lodash reject point free

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Is it possible to avoid point in this example?

```
_.reject([1, 4, null, undefined, 2, 5], item => _.isNull(item) || _.isUndefined(item));
// -> [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reject all items that are `undefined` or `null` using [`_.isNil()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isNil):

```js
const result = _.reject([1, 4, null, undefined, 2, 5], _.isNil);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use `_.compact` instead of `_.reject`:

For details see [this](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#compact) link.